# How do I define a printable area?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my application, there is much contents, in which i would like to `print` the whole page using jQuery - I can use `window.print()` - in case if i wish to print a part of position from the content how to can define that part alone printable in a page..

some thing like this:

```
<div id="printable">
    <p>Print this div!</p>

</div>

<button> Print Contents </button>

$('button').on('click', function(){
    var printable = $('#printable');
    window.print(printable);
});
```

And another request I am adding here is, some time in the app, i am getting muliple result as pagination. I would like to print all the pages too... what would be the correct way. whether using `jQuery` or any other `plug-ins` ?

Thanks in advance.

Please requesting to update here:

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zhbrspw8/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `@media` attribute

```
<style type="text/css">
    @media print
    {
        body * { visibility: hidden; }
        #printable * { visibility: visible; }
    }
</style>
```

[**Demo Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/zhbrspw8/2/)

Comment: What about the multiple pages, in case if i get in the pagination?

Comment: unfortunately window.print() print only the current page. But you can make window.open('<html with all pages>') and window.print().